# SharePoint Communication Site Document Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, communication-site

I have an SP Communication site with normal user view access. There is a document library as well. Is it possible for when a visitor clicks on the document that they have to request access to the site admin for it? Or the site admin gets notified of the request, but the user never gets the document, they just initiate a request for access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Access requests are for unauthorized users.

Since the user has view permission for the site, he could also access documents that inherit permissions from the site.

Only when the user has no access to the document, he needs access request for it.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3#ID0EAACAAA=SharePoint_in_Microsoft_365